# redux-saga with hooks not working, invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

I'm trying to make redux-saga with hooks on form work properly but I cannot find a way to make it work the way I want. console tells me that I need to execute hook only in my functionnal body component, which I do in fact but it's not working.

Things I tried :

- Call the hook in the component
- Call the hook inside the onSubmit callback of formik
- Tried to return a callback to avoid the instant call of my custom hook in the `core/notifications/index.ts`

Here is the hook :

```
function useUpdateNotifications(subscriptions: FormatedSubscription) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const formatSubscriptions = valuesIn(subscriptions);
  return () =>
    dispatch(Events.updateNotifications(formatSubscriptions as Subscription[]));
}
```

and the place I call it :

```
const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: formatedValues,
  onSubmit: (values: FormatedSubscription) => {
    Core.updateNotifications(values);
  }
});
```

You can find the sandbox with the same issue here https://codesandbox.io/s/hook-formik-sagas-issues-3pq62

**`core/notifications/index.tsx`**

My hooks for notifications and all logic are there. I have my sagas, selectors and then I create my hooks with the useDispatch (useSelector etc). The hooks `useUpdateNotifications` (used for dispatching an Event plugged to one of my sagas) for example is called in the **`src/index.tsx`** when I submit my formik form. But when I'm submitting my form, the console shows a Warning telling me that hooks should be called inside the body of a function component. It's exactly what I did.

Do you have some advices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I find the solution, the how and the why. Here are the explanations :

- I was calling my hook with an argument instead of defering it to my callback inside with my dispatch. Of course, according to the doc, We need to call de hook first and my mistake was a misunderstanding of this. I came with this solution working pretty well now :

```
function useUpdateNotifications() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (items: FormatedSubscription) => {
    const formatSubscriptions = valuesIn(items);
    dispatch(Events.updateNotifications(formatSubscriptions as Subscription[]));
  };
}
```

And I was able to call it simply with this without typescript error asking me "Expect 1 argument but got 0" :

```
const updateNotifications = Core.updateNotifications();
updateNotifications(notifications);
```

Hope it will help someone in the future.